# Angular program menu component template not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to add a menu component in Angular 6. All worked fine but the menu component template.
The Problem is browser giving the error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/app/menu/menu.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './menu/menu.component.html' in '/home/fly/myangular/conFusion/src/app/menu'
```

In `menu.component.ts` I have templateUrl address in Component decorator.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  template: `
    <p>
      menu worksx!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [],
  templateUrl: './menu/menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu/menu.component.scss']
})
```

And this is my `menu.component.html` view:

```
<div class="container"
     fxLayout="column"
     fxLayoutGap="10px">

  <mat-list fxFlex>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
      <img matListAvatar src={{ dish.image }} alt={{ dish.name }}>
      <h1 matLine> {{ dish.name }} </h1>
      <p matLine>
        <span> {{ dish.description }} </span>
      </p>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>

</div>
```

PS: This is my project structure:
[image]

---

**Edit:**
After fixing the template address, the page gone white, 
This is my console:

```
MenuComponent.html:7 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '}}' is not a valid attribute name.
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:83639:16)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/animations.js.BaseAnimationRenderer.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82265:23)
    at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.setAttribute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52472:23)
    at createElement (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49144:22)
    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51370:26)
    at createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51317:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52354:25)
    at Object.debugCreateEmbeddedView [as createEmbeddedView] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51855:12)
    at TemplateRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49904:38)
    at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49770:35)
View_MenuComponent_1 @ MenuComponent.html:7
MenuComponent.html:7 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_
View_MenuComponent_1 @ MenuComponent.html:7
core.js:3121 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
%7B%7B:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'; 
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import 'hammerjs';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';

import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Jacopos answer should fix it. The thing is `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` should be relative paths from your **.ts** file to your template **.html** and style files, which, in your case, are in the same directory.

Comment: @ngfelixl I fixed that, but now the page is full white not rendering anything. Any idea?

Comment: Open dev-tools and tell us the console tabs output.

Comment: if you are getting blank page remove everything and just add some dummy values and check and also give padding-top and left sometimes contents will be hidden at the top

Comment: import "hammerjs" in main.ts file not in main module

Comment: @chethu I've added now on main.ts, but no change

Comment: in your menu.component.html remove everything and just add <h1>Something.....</h1> just check whether u are getting this

Comment: @chethu Yes, I got Something..

Comment: you are getting any error now in console window

Comment: No error, all well

Comment: then try this <div class="container"
     fxLayout="column"
     fxLayoutGap="10px">

  <mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dish of dishes">
      <img matListAvatar src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.nam }}>
      <h1 > {{ dish.name }} </h1>
      <p >
        <span> {{dish.description}} </span>
      </p>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>

</div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181927/discussion-between-adil-saju-and-chethu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solve the problem myself. The problem was under `menu.component.html`,
in the line:

```
   <img matListAvatar src={{ dish.image }} alt={{ dish.name }}>
```

**the file cannot identify the `src` location without `""`.**

fixed by:

```
   <img matListAvatar src="{{ dish.image }}" alt="{{ dish.name }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

The component should be like this: (without the arrows)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['menu.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: I did, the error is gone but the page is not rendering the view `menu.component.html`. The page is full white now!

Comment: You should use only `templateUrl` and remove `template`

Comment: what about removing `template` and `styles` from the component decorator?

Comment: I removed, but no change.

Comment: `./menu/menu.component.html` is refering to a subdirectory from menu.component.ts relatively, so you have to use `./menu.component.html` and `./menu.component.scss` instead

Comment: change template url to './menu.component.html' and css to ['./menu.component.css']

Comment: still nothing :(

Comment: don't use both template and templateUrl remove template and also remove styles

Comment: Are you rendering the component? I mean, in your main .html did you have this? `<app-menu></app-menu>`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Yes I have it

Comment: I had imported the `MenuComponent`, but do I have to bootstrap `MenuComponent`?

Comment: @AdilSaju can you add to your code the `app.module` and the html code you get from your whole page when is loaded? I believe the component isn't rendered, not just the html. You cancheck it with putting a breakpoint in the `constructor` of your `MenuComponent`. Another thing could be that `ngFor` nor cycling properly. HAve you tried commeting all the html code and simply putting `<h1>It works!</h1` to see if you still see a blank page?

Comment: Perfect, can you please add the full code of `MenuComponent` ? @AdilSaju